# How can extract default values for automatic virtual topology using python?

Tags: python, abaqus

Hi all and thank you in advance,

I am currently trying to extract Abaqus's default calculated virtual topology values (image). I can not seem to find how to extract the default values using python in the script reference guides.

Any ideas on how to extract these default values?

Thank you again.

[image: Abaqus default topology values]

Comment: The first step would probably be locating the config file where the default values are stored. http://media.3ds.com/support/simulia/public/v69ef/installation_and_licensing_guides/books/sgb69ef/default.htm?startat=ch04s01.html

Comment: Hi Jonas, Abaqus calculates some of these values based on the geometry.

Comment: To clarify, are you wanting to extract how Abaqus *calculates* the default values, or are you just wanting to extract the default parameters after clicking "Defaults" in that dialogue box?